# How to convert pandas DataFrame to json for django model?

Tags: python, json, django, pandas

I have the Pandas DataFrame below and need to convert it to json format with the df.columns wrapped in a Django model name and "fields" fieldname.  See below example of how the json should look.  How should I do this?

df:

```
+-----------------+---------+------+
|     Artist      |  Title  | Year |
+-----------------+---------+------+
| Michael Jackson | Beat it | 1988 |
| Britney Spears  | Lucky   | 2012 |
| Justin Bieber   | Baby    | 2006 |
+-----------------+---------+------+
```

Json file output:

```
[
  {
    "model": "profiles.track",
    "fields": {
      "artist": "Michael Jackson",
      "title": "Beat it",
      "year": "1988",
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "profiles.track",
    "fields": {
      "artist": "Britney Spears",
      "title": "Lucky",
      "year": "2012",
    }
  },
  {
    "model": "profiles.track",
    "fields": {
      "artist": "Justin Bieber",
      "title": "Baby",
      "year": "2006",
    }
  }
]
```

Comment: The model is always `"profiles.track"`?

Comment: Yes, the model is always "profiles.track"

Comment: Look at https://github.com/chrisdev/django-pandas and https://github.com/wq/django-rest-pandas

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can convert the dataframe `df` to a list of dictionaries with:

```
df_dicts = df.T.to_dict().values()
```

But of course that does not give us fully the requested format, nor is this a JSON blob. But we can use this as a base to extend it. We can for example wrap every dictionary into another dictionary by performing a `map`ping:

```
result = list(map(lambda x: {'model': 'profiles.track', 'fields': x}, df_dicts))
```

Finally we can construct a JSON blob with:

```
import json

json_blob = json.dumps(result)
```

This will construct a string that is a JSON dump of `result`. We can for example print it with:

```
print(json_blob)
```